# With no password expire notification at logon in Windows 7, how are you configuring password expire notification?

Tags: windows-7, password

To my understanding, Windows 7 users do not receive password expiration notification during the logon process - it occurs strictly from the system tray.

We currently have tray balloon notifications disabled to lessen user distraction, and I expect the password change process is a smoother one during the logon process rather than in an existing session.  As a result, users will get prompted to change their passwords at expiration.

The users also connect to Terminal Services boxes, but receive the advanced notification for password expiration there.  So, Windows 7 is not notifying, but TS/RDS and XP boxes are.  Any guidance on configuring this?  Personally, I would turn off all expiration notices, but I understand most users would prefer to see the notification.  Thoughts?  Any GPO or other settings I might be overlooking?  The interactive logon setting below is already enabled for our Win7 workstation GPO.  My thought is balloon notifications will get turned back on for Windows 7, but I wanted to see if anyone was aware of alternatives.  Thanks.

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies - Security Options

Interactive logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like one of those situations where you make a perfectly sensible configuration choice (disable balloon notifications to improve the user experience). Then something comes up that conflicts with that decision. At that point, you can fudge a compromise (and typically end up with a big mess, or something absurdly complicated in relation to the actual size of the problem). Alternatively, back out your change. In most cases I reckon it's best to take the learning experience, and back out of the earlier decision.

tl;dr Re-enable balloon notifications.

Comment: I think everyone misses the balloon notification about resetting passwords and even if it is enabled you still need some mechanism in place to let people know their password will expire in order to reduce the number of support calls for people who need their password reset.  The password reset prompt after expiry in Windows 7 also doesn't seem to work reliably.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post, but I finally updated the script to detect and not respond to non-expiring passwords.

```
'==========================================
' Check for password expiring notification
'==========================================
' First, get the domain policy.
'==========================================
Dim oDomain
Dim oUser
Dim maxPwdAge
Dim numDays
Dim warningDays

warningDays = 6

Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName & "")  
strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName

'========================================
' Check if password is non-expiring.
'========================================
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
    'WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
Else

    Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
    Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

    '========================================
    ' Calculate the number of days that are
    ' held in this value.
    '========================================
    numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                    maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
    'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

    '========================================
    ' Determine the last time that the user
    ' changed his or her password.
    '========================================
    Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

    '========================================
    ' Add the number of days to the last time
    ' the password was set.
    '========================================
    whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
    fromDate = Date
    daysLeft = DateDiff("d",fromDate,whenPasswordExpires)

    'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged

    if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
        Msgbox "Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and" & chr(13) & "select the 'Change a password' option", 0, "PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!"
    End if

End if

'========================================
' Clean up.
'========================================
Set oUser = Nothing
Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
Set oDomain = Nothing
```

---

This was the original answer & script

A VBS script that goes in to your GPO that displays a popup window telling the user their password expires in # days and that the user MUST click OK to dismiss.

It goes in the GPO - User Config - Policies - Admin Templates - System - Logon - Run these programs at user logon.  You will also need to add the folder location to IE Trusted Sites to avoid having a popup asking if it should run the script.

PwExpChk.vbs

```
'========================================
' First, get the domain policy.
'========================================
Dim oDomain
Dim oUser
Dim maxPwdAge
Dim numDays
Dim warningDays

warningDays = 6

Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName & "")  
strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName


Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

'========================================
' Calculate the number of days that are
' held in this value.
'========================================
numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

'========================================
' Determine the last time that the user
' changed his or her password.
'========================================
Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

'========================================
' Add the number of days to the last time
' the password was set.
'========================================
whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
fromDate = Date
daysLeft = DateDiff("d",fromDate,whenPasswordExpires)

'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged

if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
    Msgbox "Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and" & chr(13) & "select the 'Change a password' option", 0, "PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!"
End if

'========================================
' Clean up.
'========================================
Set oUser = Nothing
Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
Set oDomain = Nothing
```

Comment: We're using a method very similar to this one. They start getting nagged 2 weeks before they're due, and we include a link to the password-change-page we've written up (can't use native methods for a couple reasons). Works well.